# i would like to understand output for the folliwng sql query while joining 2 SQL table

Tags: sql

`CREATE TABLE bc (b INTEGER); INSERT INTO bc (b) VALUES (1), (1), (2), (2), (2);`

`CREATE TABLE ab (a INTEGER); INSERT INTO ab (a) VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (2);`

Table 1 have values 1,1,1,2,2
Table 2 have values 1,1,2,2,2

when i perfom joins such as `inner join` this table  `select * from ab a join bc b on a.a = b.b` i get output of 12 rows. can someone please explain the reason behind 12 rows as an output since inner join supposed to show only matching values and i have only 5 rows in table 1[image]

Comment: *when i perfom joins such as inner join*.... BUT your query has an `outer left join` so your question makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query does exactly what you ask it to do. An inner join does not give you only unique records (you could achieve that using SELECT DISTINCT ...):

there are 2 rows in a with value 1 and 3 rows in b with value one giving you 2 x 3 = 6 rows of results. there are 3 rows with value 2 in a and two rows with value 2 in b giving you another 6 matching rows so you do get back the right amount of rows.

Hope that clears things up for you